# Connect PlanetScale to Netlify

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, netlify, planetscale

I try to connect my React Next application between `PlanetScale` and `Netlify`, but I fail and the console return an 'internal server error 500'.

I've following the tutorial https://planetscale.com/docs/tutorials/deploy-to-netlify

I create a new password, like is said for the case where the password is blurred.

In `Netlify` I copy for the value like : `mysql://l2z8tqg7e0us84ikh14p:****************@aws.connect.psdb.cloud/animal?sslaccept=strict`  where the `*****` is my new password generated...